# const qualifier end of function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
   int x, y; // Private data members

public:
   Point(int x = 0, int y = 0); // Constructor
   int getX() const; // Getters
   int getY() const;
   void setX(int x); // Setters
   void setY(int y);
   void print() const;
   const Point operator+(const Point & rhs);
         // Overload '+' operator as member function of the class
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Point p1(1, 2), p2(4, 5);
   // Use overloaded operator +
   Point p3 = p1 + p2;
   p1.print();  // (1,2)
   p2.print();  // (4,5)
   p3.print();  // (5,7)

   // Invoke via usual dot syntax, same as p1+p2
   Point p4 = p1.operator+(p2);
   p4.print();  // (5,7)

   // Chaining
   Point p5 = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
   p5.print();  // (15,21)


    return 0;
}

// Constructor - The default values are specified in the declaration
Point::Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { } // Using initializer list

// Getters
int Point::getX() const { return x; }
int Point::getY() const { return y; }



// Setters
void Point::setX(int x) { this->x

= x;  }   // (*this).x = x; x = x
void Point::setY(int y) { this->y = y; }

// Public Functions
void Point::print() const {
   cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
}

// Member function overloading '+' operator
const Point Point::operator+(const Point & rhs) {
   return Point(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y);
}
```

I'm studying operator overloading and I don't understand why I get the error.

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const Point' and 'Point')
```

I deleted `const` qualifier at the end of the `operator+` function on purpose in order to understand it. Can someone explain explicitly why I need it?

Comment: In addition to the member function constness requirement for function chaining, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890302/chaining-operation-and-order-of-evaluation-on-the-same-object - for a related chaining gotcha (just so you don't go on another 2-hour headscratcher) ;)

Answer (score 2):

The member

```
const Point Point::operator+(const Point & rhs);
```

is a non-const member, i.e. requires the lhs of the operation to be mutable, but (as the error message shows) you require an operation with a `const` lhs. Hence, you must declare the operator as such

```
Point Point::operator+(const Point & rhs) const;
```

Note that I also removed the `const` for the return type, as it is deprecated.

---

**Why do you need the `const`?** The natural `+` operator (for example between arithmetic types) does not alter its arguments and, as a consequence, the usual (human) conventions for using this operator implicitly assume that the arguments are not altered. In your particular case, the return of `a+b` was explicitly `const` (though that is deprecated AFAIK), so that in `a+b+c` = `(a+b)+c` the lhs is `const` and your non-const member function cannot be used.

Moreover, whenever a member function does not alter the state of its object, it should be declared `const`, so that it can be called for `const` object.

---

Alternatively, this operator can be defined as non-member function friend

```
Point operator+(const Point&lhs, const Point&rhs);
```

which more clearly expresses the symmetry between lhs and rhs (the corresponding function for your non-const member would have been

```
Point operator+(Point&lhs, const Point&rhs);
```

).

Comment: The `const` in return type *has* effects (as forbid `(a + b) = c`), but it is deprecated and disallow some optimization.

Comment: "i.e. requires the lhs of the operation to be a lvalue" - This is wrong, it requires the lhs to be *mutable*, but it's fine if it's an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your method as a `const`one, *i.e.*:

```
const Point operator+(const Point & rhs) const;
```

`p1+p2` returns a `const Point` so you need a `const Point + const Point` operator to be able to compute `(p1+p2)+p3`.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers, but they don't explain *why* the const is an issue. The simple reason is chaining order and operator type matching.

```
Point p5 = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
// is interpreted as:
Point p5 = ConstPoint( (Point(p1)).operator+((const Point&)(p2)) + p3 + p4;
// as operator+ is left-to-right , not right-to-left !!!
```

Point and const Point are different types, so in the first iterpretation, you have a:

```
p5 = const Point(sumP1P2) . operator+ (Point(P3)) /*+ P4 awaiting interpretation */;
// whose search will be for a const LHS - i.e. "Point operator=(constPointRef) const;" - which is bound to fail.
```

The following will work:

```
const P& operator+(const P& rhs) const; // corresponds to const P& result = const P& lhs + const P& rhs
P operator+(P rhs) const; // corresponds to copy-by-value for all operands.
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem is "const" Point operator+(const Point & rhs); remove that in the def and dec .. it will work

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was *why* he needs `const`.

Comment: Your answer is right David Schwartz for the question he asked, but he is just started learning. So obviously I was giving why the problem occurred because of the constant on the return type ..  That way he will learn what is const in return.